# SQLite Maximum matching row by multi column with value

Tags: database, sqlite, search, rows

test table

```
ID  a   b   c   d   e   (f to z)
--------------------------------
0   2   7   9   0   8   ...
1   4   5   6   3   0   ... 
2   1   5   6   2   9   ...
3   1   0   8   2   3   ...
4   2   1   6   9   5   ...
5   1   5   6   2   3   ...
6   2   3   4   1   0   ...
```

I want to find the row that matches the most columns to my query. What I have now is

```
select ID from test where a = 1, b = 5, c = 6, d = 2, e = 3, ... (same with f to z)
```

The desired output from the sample above is: 5, 2, 3, 1, 4

How do I write a query like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the closest match over multiple columns, the easiest may be to count the number of column wise matches and order by that, descending.

```
SELECT ID
FROM myTable
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN a = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN b = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN c = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN d = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN e = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC;

# ID: 5 2 3 1 4 0 6
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/596ac/1).

Comment: Boolean expressions already return 1/0; `CASE WHEN b = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` is the same as `(b = 5)`.

Comment: @CL. Ah, didn't know SQLite had the same "loosely typed" boolean as MySQL. PostgreSQL for example would bail on just summing up booleans.